# Render stucked at 100% with 16/40 Tiles done (2.78)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, versions

I have a problem with rendering in Blender - it got stucked on 100%, but only 16 from 40 Tiles were done. Additionaly, it doesn't show number of actually processing samples like it was in the previous versions (maybe it can be set somewhere?). When I hit Esc button after some time to stop it,  in final result it showed me one more title done then it could be seen on preview. It looks like that maybe preview and procentage bar was bugged, but anyway render after this time should be already done at all.
[image]
[image]

Comment: is the inteface responsive still? Do you really need 3000 samples? How big are your render tiles?

Comment: 256x256, render on GPU. I set 3000 samples because It is really a simple scene. When I rendered it today it takes +/- 10 minutes. Finally samples number was visible and whole render was done, but progress bar still was stucked on 100% (when only half scene was rendered - near 21 titles). It doesn't hurt that much (render finally worked) but i'm afraid if it is some kind of bug, bigger scenes will not render correctly to the end. It happend to me only in 2.78.